# Rails: Add border in axlsx

Tags: excel, export-to-excel, axlsx

Using `axlsx` it is possible to add border. I added something like this

```
red_border = p.workbook.styles.add_style :border => { :style => :thin, :color => "FFFF0000" }
```

But this gives border on all sides of a cell. But I need only top and bottom border of a cell not left and right border. How can I implement that? So that my border show only top and bottom.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution [here](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/randym/axlsx/Axlsx%2FStyles%3Aparse_border_options). Just use edge attributes with top and bottom.

```
red_border = p.workbook.styles.add_style :border => { :style => :thin, :color => "FFFF0000", :edges => [:top, :bottom] }
```

Comment: Accept your answer.